# Solr - Parent child documents

Tags: solr, lucene, spring-data-solr

I need to store parent - child documents in solr and need an ability to apply filter to both parent and child record and return both parent and child document as a single record in the response. Does anyone has any idea if this can be achieved using solr?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your exact requirement is. However, you can explore block join query parser (Here's [a link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers)) which lets you query hierarchical documents.